# Addining row number of sub dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
> df1
  var1 var2 var3
1   ac   bc   bc
2   bc   bc   cc
3   dc   ec   dc
4   gc   gc   gc
```

I have a sub dataframe from the above df1 (only 2 rows remained of the 4):

```
> df2
  var1 var2 var3
2   bc   bc   cc
3   dc   ec   dc
```

I would like to get the numbers of df2 into r (`r = 2,3`).
In addition I would like to add to df1 a new column that will indicate by 1 that the row exists in df2.
In final df1 will be the following:

```
> df1
  var1 var2 var3 df2
1   ac   bc   bc  0
2   bc   bc   cc  1
3   dc   ec   dc  1
4   gc   gc   gc  0
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%`to compare the rownames of 'df1' and 'df2'.  We get a logical vector which can be coerced to binary format by wrapping with `+`.

```
 df1$newcol <- +(rownames(df1) %in% rownames(df2))
 df1
 #  var1 var2 var3 newcol
 #1   ac   bc   bc      0
 #2   bc   bc   cc      1
 #3   dc   ec   dc      1
 #4   gc   gc   gc      0
```

If we need the row names that are common, use `intersect`

```
intersect(rownames(df1), rownames(df2))
#[1] "2" "3"
```